# How to add domain configuration file?

Tags: flutter, configuration

Is there a way to add a configuration file for flutter app?

Use case as following:

A software vendor developed a client/server application. client is flutter app. Release is binary code, not flutter package.

CompanyA deployed it with domain company-a.com. companyB deployed it with domain company-b.com.

```
  flutter_app -------- Sever1
                      company-a.com

  flutter_app -------- Sever2
                      company-b.com
```

The flutter client needs to know the domain to connect to the right server.

When an end user downloads the flutter app from AppStore and GooglePlay, the app must have the domain already configured.

Does the domain need to be hard-coded in flutter app? If so, the flutter client app must be re-built for every deployment. That is, the flutter app can not be pre-built for download.